# Creating batch SQL to purge data based on date

Tags: sql-server

I have a request to purge data from a SQL Server database fairly regularly (monthly ideally). The database itself is no longer attached to an application layer and is purely used for reporting.

I've identified the column I would like to use, with a date format 'YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS.xxx'.

However I would like to contain this in a batch script so I can execute this from task scheduler with no user input.

The end result would be something like:

```
DELETE FROM [TABLE] 
WHERE [DATE OPEN] <= (today's date, minus 6 years)
```

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DATEADD for that.

```
--SELECT Query to check records first.
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [DATE OPEN] <= DATEADD(year,-6,GETDATE())

--DELETE Query to actually check records.
DELETE FROM [TABLE] WHERE [DATE OPEN] <= DATEADD(year,-6,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GETDATE() for today's date.